# if statement not evaluating correctly bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am testing if a variable is greater than another variable.  The if evaluation is getting the same value no matter what the values are.

```
COMP(){
avg=$(for avg in $(for file in $(ls /var/log/sa/sa[0123]*); do echo $file; done); do sar -r -f $avg| tail -1; done | awk '{totavg+=$4} END {print (totavg/NR)*5}');
for comp in $(sar -r -f /var/log/sa/sa08 | egrep -v "^$|Average|CPU|used" | awk '{print $5}'); do
        if [ `echo $avg` <  `echo $comp` ];
                then echo 'You have had a spike!';
                echo "COMP = $comp";
                echo "AVG = $avg";
        fi;
done }
```

I am getting this output even though the values are not really evaluating to true.

```
You have had a spike!
COMP = 41.20
AVG = 145.438
You have had a spike!
COMP = 41.20
AVG = 145.438
You have had a spike!
COMP = 41.19
AVG = 145.438
You have had a spike!  
COMP = 41.24 
AVG = 145.438
```

I have tried this multiple ways but can not get it working.  Any ideas?

Comment: `for avg in $(for file in $(ls /var/log/sa/sa[0123]*); do echo $file; done); do` ... is this a joke?? You mean `for avg in /var/log/sa/sa[0123]*; do`, don't you?

Comment: This would have fit better on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There are so many things to change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep as ingnacio has pointed out

```
average=`echo $avg`;
comp1=`echo $comp`

  if ((average)) 2>/dev/null; then
     average=$((average))
   else
     average=0;
  fi
 if ((comp1)) 2>/dev/null; then
     comp1=$((comp1))
  else
     comp1=0;
  fi

if [ $average -lt $comp1 ];then
```

Answer (score 1):

`<` compares lexicographically. If you want to compare integers then use `-lt`. If you want to compare floating point numbers then use `bc` instead of `test`.

Comment: It's worse than that, since `<` isn't quoted or escaped it'll be treated as an input redirect rather than an operator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for numerical comparison or literal (string) comparison? Different operators may be needed depending on which one.